# Repository pattern with Specification queries

Tags: java, repository, mvp, rx-java

I'm working on an Android (Java) project which utilizes different analytic metrics (sum of x group by date, sum of x group by id, etc) and I am projecting the data sets into different charts using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

For the backend, I'm following the MVP architecture and applying a [Repository pattern](https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006#.h8ra0ofr8) for querying from Realm database. Mind you, I haven't had enough experience in applying Repository pattern into a project, so this might be my early trial and error.

---

Right now, I have a base Repository which contains all the generic queries:

```
public interface Repository<T> {

    Observable<T> find();

    Observable<List<T>> findAll();

    Observable<T> add(T model);

    Observable<Iterable<T>> add(Iterable<T> items);

    Observable<String> update(T model);

    Observable<String> remove(T model);

    Observable<List<T>> query(Specification specification);

}
```

`Specification` is an empty marker class which being extended by more specific Specification interfaces, for example `ChartSpecification extends Specification`.

In my `ChartSpecification` interface has one method called `mapToChart`

```
public interface ChartSpecification<To, From extends RealmModel> extends Specification {

    List<To> mapToChart(RealmResults<From> results);

}
```

This is how I implement the concrete method for mapToChart inside `MyModelCountPerMonth`. Why I do it this way is to make sure I create one class per unique query. For example:

```
public class MyModelCountPerMonth implements RealmSpecification<MyModel>, ChartSpecification<Charting, MyModel> {

    @Override
    public RealmResults<MyModel> toRealmResults(Realm realm) {
        return realm.where(MyModel.class)
                .findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Charting> mapToChart(RealmResults<MyModel> results) {

        // do MyModel model mapping to Charting model

        // X and Y coordinates are set here into Charting model


        return mappedChartData;
    }
}
```

So, the query is done by `MyModelRepositoryImpl` class:

```
public class MyModelRepositoryImpl implements Repository<MyModel> {

    // some initialization and other method overriding

    @Override
    public Observable<List<MyModel>> query(Specification specification) {

        if (specification instanceof MyModelCountPerMonth) {
            return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super List<MyModel>> subscriber) -> {
                try {
                    final MyModelCountPerMonth realmSpecification = (MyModelCountPerMonth) specification;

                    final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    final RealmResults<MyModel> realmResults = realmSpecification.toRealmResults(realm);

                    realm.close();
                    final List<Charting> chartData = realmSpecification.mapToChart(realmResults);

                    subscriber.onNext(chartData); // this gives error because Observable returns List<MyModel> instead
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            });
        }

        // there may be more if statements here if required

        return null;
    }

}
```

From here, I could just call this Repository and subscribe on the `query` data and return it to the View.

```
myModelRepo.query(new MyModelCountPerMonth())
        .subscribe(chartingList -> 
            if (chartingList.size() > 0) {
                mView.onRequestDatasetSuccess(chartingList);
            } else {
                mView.showEmpty();
            }
        );
```

So, back to my question. Referring to `MyModelRepositoryImpl`, the error I'm getting is at `onNext` since the Observable from Repository only returns `List<MyModel>`, instead I want it to return `List<Charting>`. But by doing that, doesn't it violates the SRP rule because it has side-effects (toRealmResults and mapToChart)?

How do I make it so that the MyModel Specification can do both RealmResult and mapping of the data into Charting model?

Do I need to separate the ChartSpecification and just do it in the Presenter after retrieving data from repository?

Thanks!